# Adding string inside another string

Tags: php, string, replace

Well let's say I have the string: `file.mp3`. How can i modify it with PHP dynamically like `file_0.mp3` based on the file's extension. So that `_0` is always before the extension?

Comment: What are the strings like? You could use a regex or maybe even `str_replace`. In your current example `$string = str_replace('.', '_0.', $string);` i think would do it.

Comment: What do you mean by `What are the strings like`?

Comment: The `file.mp3` is the `.` the only `.` and always preceding the file extension? Could you have files without extensions?

Comment: Well the string may contain more than one `.`. So the example you gave may not be useful

Comment: Okay, so can you provide some more examples? Will files without extensions be expected, are hidden files expected?

Comment: No, there sure will have extensions

Comment: Maybe a regex like, https://regex101.com/r/kZ9bJ7/1. Then run that with `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this dynamically and you're unsure if the string may contain more than one ".", here:

```
<?php

$string = 'file.mp3';

$ext = strrpos($string, '.'); // find the last "dot"
$newname = substr($string, 0, $ext) . '_0' . substr($string, $ext);

echo $newname;
```